# Update tkinter Label to display a text file, one line at a time on my python GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm creating my first GUI using tkinter. I have several classes created already but need help with this one. I'm trying to read a line of a file, display it on the GUI using a label, read the next line and update the label.. and so on until I reach the end of the file.  (Not actually reading sensor values, it's just a dummy function created. Instead I'm reading in data from a .txt file)

I'm not sure how to do this. Any feedback would help.

```
class HealthWindow(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.configure(background='gray')  # change bg color
    label = Label(self, text="Health Status", bg="gray", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Main",
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(FirstWindow)) 
 # ttk buttons are better looking
    button1.pack()
    displayline = Label(self, text="", font=LARGE_FONT)
    displayline.pack()

    def readSensor():
        with open("data.txt") as f:
            #for line in f:
                #time.sleep(2)
            temp = f.readline()
            displayline.configure(text=str(temp))

    def update():
        readSensor()
        self.after(1000, update)

    buttonClick = ttk.Button(self, text="View Status", command= lambda: 
readSensor())  # ttk buttons are better looking
    buttonClick.pack()
```

Comment: if you will always open file then you will always read only first line. You have to open file only once, and keep it open when you read line in `readSensor()`

Comment: BTW: do you have to create function inside another function ? can't you create normal method in class - with `self` ?

Comment: You never call `update`, so what you expect? It's also malicious to open a file each time `update` is called.

Comment: you can use `command=readSensor` - without `()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to open file only once - ie. in `__init__` - and then read line by line.

```
class HealthWindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.configure(background='gray')  # change bg color

        label = Label(self, text="Health Status", bg="gray", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Main",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(FirstWindow)) 
        button1.pack()

        # with self. to have access in other methods
        self.displayline = Label(self, text="", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.displayline.pack()

        buttonClick = ttk.Button(self, text="View Status", command=self.update)
        buttonClick.pack()

        # open only once
        self.f = open("data.txt")

    # method,not internal function
    def update(self):
        try:
            temp = self.f.readline()
            self.displayline["text"] = temp
            self.after(1000, self.update)
        except Exception as ex:
            print('Error:', ex)
            print('Probably end of file')
            self.f.close()
```

BTW: you still need to check if file is not open when you click `update` second time.

---

**EDIT:** now button runs `start_update` which checks if file is already open.

I use `self.f = None` to control it.

`after` still runs `update`, not `start_update`.

```
class HealthWindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.configure(background='gray')  # change bg color

        label = Label(self, text="Health Status", bg="gray", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Main",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(FirstWindow)) 
        button1.pack()

        self.displayline = Label(self, text="", font=LARGE_FONT)
        self.displayline.pack()

        buttonClick = ttk.Button(self, text="View Status", command=self.start_update)
        buttonClick.pack()

        self.f = None # to see if it is open when you click button next time

    def start_update(self):
        if self.f is None:
            # open only once
            self.f = open("data.txt")
            self.update()        

    def update(self):
        temp = self.f.readline()
        self.displayline["text"] = temp

        if temp: # there was text in file
            self.after(1000, self.update)
        else:
            print('Probably end of file')
            self.f.close()
            self.f = None # so you can open again
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I made the corrections and now I'm receiving this error:  buttonClick = ttk.Button(self, text="View Status", command=self.start_update)
AttributeError: 'HealthWindow' object has no attribute 'start_update'

Comment: did you made correct indentions ? Indentions are very important in Python. They can change everything. See indentions in answer.

Comment: I fixed my indentations and this worked! Thanks so much!